# Signals sent to the child process from a parent process is ignored inside a docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ffmpeg, docker-compose, fastapi

I have a Python REST API server built with FastAPI. Upon response, it spawns a ffmpeg sub-process which is used to capture a video from an RTSP stream provided by an IP camera. Upon another request, the app stops recording the video by sending a SIGTERM signal to the ffmpeg process.

This works just fine outside of Docker, but in a container, the SIGTERM is ignored by the ffmpeg process, thus the video never stops recording. I tried adding the `--init` option to my container but it didn't help although my app didn't have PID 1 anymore.

My Dockerfile:

```
# convert poetry's pyproject.toml into a requirements.txt file
FROM python:3.9 as requirements-stage
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN pip install poetry
COPY ./pyproject.toml ./poetry.lock* /tmp/
RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --without-hashes

# actual app deployment
FROM python:3.9
RUN apt update && apt install -y usbutils zlib1g libjpeg-dev ffmpeg
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=requirements-stage /tmp/requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /requirements.txt
COPY . /
ENV IS_DOCKERIZED true
CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  ipfs_node:
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:v0.8.0
    volumes:
      - ~/ipfs/ipfs_staging:/export
      - ~/ipfs/ipfs_data:/data/ipfs
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "4001:4001"

  feecc_io_gateway:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    init: true
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - "./output:/output"
      - "/dev/usb:/dev/usb"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was trying to figure this out, I created another [topic](https://forums.docker.com/t/signal-sent-to-the-child-process-from-a-parent-process-is-ignored-inside-a-docker-container/117282) on the Docker forum.

We weren't able to make it work using signals, however I found a workaround. In my case with ffmpeg, instead of sending a SIGTERM / SIGINT signal to the process, I can send the "Q" key to the stdin. This has worked for me.